# Will social sharing help my website rank in search engines?

Tags: seo, search-engines, ranking, social-media

I am owner of travel related website and recently found that two twitter users have shared a link from my website on their profile. Those profiles are not related to travel.

One profile is sharing images on his profile and other one is sharing quotes. But both profiles have more than 10000 followers and each tweet got more than 10-15 likes and 3-7 shares.

Is this OK for my website? Will help my website in search engine rankings or not?

Comment: See also: [Twitter vs. Facebook vs. Google+ in terms of influence on rankings.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49685/twitter-vs-facebook-vs-google-in-terms-of-influence-on-rankings) and [Do links on social media sites improve my SEO? If yes, what determines the how much they help?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101192/do-links-on-social-media-sites-improve-my-seo-if-yes-what-determines-the-how-m)

Answer (score 2):

Google has said many times that they do not use social shares as a ranking signal:

- 2014: [Google's Matt Cutts: We Don't Use Twitter Or Facebook Social Signals To Rank Pages](https://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-facebook-twitter-pages-are-treated-like-any-other-web-page-on-the-internet-182370)
- 2015: [Google: Again, Social Signals Do Not Influence Your Ranking](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-social-signals-ranking-20803.html)
- 2016: [Social Sharing and Social Ads Have No Impact on RankBrain](http://www.thesempost.com/social-links-social-sharing-have-no-impact-on-rankbrain/)

[SEO Moz points out](https://moz.com/blog/relationship-between-organic-rankings-and-social-shares) that many webmasters notice that their most highly shared articles on social media also get the most search engine traffic.   SEO Moz chalks this up to correlation with article quality and engagement.   Better, more engaging articles get more shares, more links, and a high click through rate from the search results.

At best, social shares may attract users that end up linking to your content or start searching for your brand name.   Social shares (and advertising) may [indirectly help SEO through these mechanisms](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/social-media-seo/196185/).

Answer (score 0):

- Everything is OK, what drives organic traffic to your site. (organic == natural == good, artificial == by bots == bad)
- Any link or mention helping people to find your site is OK.
- Whether your referrer (ressource linking to you) is or isn't related to your topic is not very important.
- Much more important is, whether visitors coming from outta web (from sites, twitter or facebook accounts linking to you) find your site interesting. Finding interesting means read, interact, mention, link back.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, whatever the website we own, social sharing plays a vital role in enhancing the reaches of post as well as there are higher chances of getting a minimum traffic from those posts, which increases the website visibility & build a customer base. but it is recommended to share only in the relevant profiles, if not there are great chances of blocking & removing the content from those profiles.

Comment: They asked if it affected ranking, not traffic or reaches.

Answer (score -1):

One of Google's search algorithm ranking signals is social shares. Google expects a good site to receive a steady amount of social shares on a regular basis. Because Google knows that users who like a site will sometimes tend to share that site's content on their social media platforms.

If a website is receiving very low amounts of social shares, Google sees this as a negative ranking factor. It indicates to Google that the users it sends to your site don't like your pages very much, otherwise there would be a certain percentage of them that share your content.

Because most people on social media don't have dedicated channels to specific niches, Google understands that when a social media user shares your content, it doesn't have to be 100% related to their profile's general niche.

A social media share from your site is simply being counted as a vote by the sharer, as him saying "hey this site is good!". The more followers and activity that social media user has, the higher the ranking signal that Google receives. If a social media profile has 100k followers and a lot of activity, Google trusts that profile more than it trusts a new Twitter profile with 100 followers and no activity. And so the more trust it has towards the social media profile, the more trust it has in the social media share of your site in its ranking factor.

Getting shares on social media is a very good thing, regardless of almost anyone who shares your content.

Comment: I'm not sure that Google even has access to social share data from Facebook.   They did at one point a few years ago, but I believe FB shut down that access.  Shares on other platforms such as Twitter and Google+ are so small in comparison that Google probably doesn't have enough data to base rankings on social shares at this point.

Comment: @stephen Google crawls social media profiles and discovers links from that profile to the website and notices that as a social signal. It can also track social traffic and some sharing through Analytics. Google could also be tracking user flow through its Chrome browser. Google certainly crawls social media profiles and treats inbound links as ranking signals. I think you're confusing what I said in my post to thinking I was implying that Google actually sees its users clicking on social sharing icons. If you read SEO articles you'll see that social shares are listed as a ranking factor.

Comment: Shares only show up on profiles if the share is public, so they won't see most shares. that way.   Google says they don't use any Google Analytics data for ranking purposes.   Can you link to some of the articles that back up your claims?   That would make your answer much better.